# The side bar options is not showing on the custom post's edit page

Tags: wordpress

I'm customing a post type in my wordpress, and I want to ban the sidebar in the post, but I can't find a sidebar option which in the edit page. How can I ban the sidebar in custom post type.

The sidebar option can be banned or positioned in the default post type. But when I use plugins to make a custom post type. The option is not appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the sidebar "ban" as you call it is not part of your theme, i would create a template without the sidebar in it for your custom post type

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/